# Ajax gets nothing back from the php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, apache, firefox

Jquery i dont have alert and firefox i dont have anything in return. The code was working before, database query have successfull records also. What i am missing???

1. Jquery ajax.

```
    $.ajax({
      type    : "POST",
      url     : "include/add_edit_del.php?model=teksten_display",
      data    : "oper=search&ids=" + _id ,
      dataType: "json",
      success : function(msg){
       alert(msg);
      }
     });
```

2. PHP

```
       case 'teksten_display':
           $id = $_REQUEST['ids'];           
           $res =  $_dclass->_query_sql(
               "select a,b,id,wat,c,d from tb1 where id='" . $id . "'" );
           $_rows = array();

           while ( $rows = mysql_fetch_array ($res) ) { $_rows = $rows; }
   //header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
   //header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
   header('Content-type: application/json');

           echo utf8_encode( json_encode($_rows) ) ;
           //echo json_encode($_rows);
           //var_dump($_rows);
           //print_r ($res);

           break;
```

3. Firefox response/request header

```
Date Sat, 24 Apr 2010 22:34:55 GMT
Server Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)
X-Powered-By PHP/5.1.6
Expires Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma no-cache
Content-Length 0
Connection close
Content-Type application/json

Host www.xxxx.be
User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.1.9) Gecko/20100330 Fedora/3.5.9-2.fc12 Firefox/3.5.9
Accept application/json, text/javascript, */*
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive 300
Connection keep-alive
Content-Type application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
X-Requested-With XMLHttpRequest
Referer http://www.xxxx.be/xxxxx
Content-Length 17
Cookie csdb=2; codb=5; csdbb=1; codca=1.4; csdca=3; PHPSESSID=benunvkpecqh3pmd8oep5b55t7; CAKEPHP=3t7hrlc89emvg1hfsc45gs2bl2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway, i got it, its **CentOS 5.4**, in my box:
[root@www include]# php -version
PHP 5.1.6 (cli) (built: Jan 13 2010 17:09:42) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2006 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2006 Zend Technologies
[root@www include]#

Solution: http://gargiullo.com/tag/json_encode/

Answer (score 0):

add this line to you ajax, see if there is any error

```
success : function(msg){
       alert(msg);
},
error : function(request, status, error) {
    if(status == 'parsererror' || status == 'error') {
        alert(error);
    }
}
```

Comment: I get this as alert: undefined

Comment: Alert: parseerror.

      },
       error : function(request, status, error) {
           //if(status == 'parsererror' || status == 'error') {
               alert(status);
           //}
        
        //if(status=='par)
       }

Comment: I change the database result to simple values, but still i get parseerror?
<pre><code>
case 'teksten_display':
           $id = $_REQUEST['ids'];
           $res =  $_dclass->_query_sql(
               "select '1','1','1','1','1','1' from teksten where id='" . $id . "'" );           
           $_rows = array();
           while ( $rows = mysql_fetch_array ($res) ) { $_rows = $rows; }         
           echo utf8_encode( json_encode($_rows) ) ;
           break;
</code></pre>

Comment: so you did get the error alert, then its something to do with your php. is the $_rows return something ? if you have firebug installed, trace the response in console panel

Comment: notice this select '1','1','1','1','1','1' from teksten where id='" . $id . "'" , doesnt seems to be a valid sql query to me

Comment: Mysql prompt: SELECT '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'
FROM teksten
WHERE id = '1'
LIMIT 0 , 30   , i get output : 
1  1  1  1  1  1
1  1  1  1  1  1

Comment: parseerror, for number 1, should not i think. Is it related to apache? iso-8859-1 or utf8 or text/html or page returning not really as json content type?

Comment: no, it does return json(at least as my last test), im not sure about your server setting, but you can try this , comment the header and you echo then use this exit(json_encode($_rows)); if you dont have firebug, use Developer feature in Chrome, and in you javascript do this, "console.log(typeof(msg))", see if it is a string or object(json)

Comment: I am on fedora 12/My own server is Centos 5.4. I use firefox, and firebug default.  
## console.log( ... ) tried get nothing, 
## exit(json_encode(...) ) tried , geting nothing.

Comment: hey, i paste something on your snippet. try use normal query(not using your db class), and do a simple query like "select now();"

Answer (score 0):

$.ajax success callback returns whatever you want it to return, you are returning a json OBJECT in this case and it appears as though you are expecting to just display a success message. Your msg variable actually contains an object, not a "Success!" string - in order to display something you will need to use msg['variable_from_json_object'] which will show that value.

Somethings I would look at as well in case its not your jquery that is causing problems in your call to utf8_encode, does this method work to convert an entire json object, or does it need to be run on each item BEFORE its converted to json? json remember is an object, its not a string.

You may look at [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php#75422) to get a better idea of how you can convert your array to uft8, then to json.

```
echo json_encode(utf8_encode_array($_rows));
```

with the method supplied in the link possibly..

Lastly, in order to make sure your json is being created successfully, visit the url you are call as ajax, as a normal page: **include/add_edit_del.php?model=teksten_display&oper=search&ids=" + _id.** of course replacing _id with a value just for testing. I think that you may see an issue here as your url should not include query parameters, they should all be in your data if you are going to use that parameter.. I would expect something of either of the following:

```
  $.ajax({
  type    : "POST",
  url     : "include/add_edit_del.php",
  data    : "model=teksten_display&oper=search&ids=" + _id,
  dataType: "json",
  success : function(msg){
   alert(msg);
  }
 });
```

OR not using the data parameter at all and cramming it into the url, because url expect NO query parameters (?var=foo), when it sees data it replaces the url parameters with values supplied within data

```
  $.ajax({
  type    : "POST",
  url     : "include/add_edit_del.php?model=teksten_display&oper=search&ids=" + _id",
  dataType: "json",
  success : function(msg){
   alert(msg);
  }
 });
```

Good luck!

Comment: Tried: include/add_edit_del.php?model=teksten_display&oper=search&ids=1

Output: empty page

Didnt helped../solved

Comment: The whole thing, that i  posted, is a working script. I did a server migration, after that its not working. Now i am confused where is wrong, "THE CODE WAS WORKING".....

Comment: The same code that works in my local box but doesnt work in server is here: http://dpaste.de/Hxr5/

Comment: If this already worked, and now doesnt, and no code was changed, this is a server configuration issue not a code issue. Posting code isnt going to help anyone solve this problem. You need to post information pertaining to the differences in server/local setup, OS, PHP Versions, MySQL versions, MySQL database types and so on.. lets go from there..